# UICollectionView.dequeueReusableCell crashes

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

In `viewDidLoad` I register the cell like this:

```
let cellIdentifier = "Cell"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "ViewCell", bundle: nil)
    collection.register(cellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
}
```

and in `cellForItemAt` of the `UICollectionViewDataSource` I do:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // It crashes while trying to dequeue with the Error message:  Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:]
    let dequedCell = collection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    return dequedCell
}
```

The onlystrange thing might be that the code is Mixed Swift/ObjC, and `ViewCell` is ObjC and gets imported in the bridging header:

```
#import "ViewCell.h"
```

I am getting the following error:

> *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewC‌​ategory:],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UI‌​Kit-3600.7.47/UIColl‌​ectionView.m:5106

I made sure all names are correct. Does anyone know why this crash is happening??

Comment: Can you add the exact error log?

Comment: The exact error is `*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.7.47/UICollectionView.m:5106`

Comment: Are you sure you spelled the nib name correctly? Check it again. I had a situation where filename string contained some invisible character.

Comment: I have triple checked all names. You may believe me, they are correct.

Comment: And you assigned cell Identifier in the xib file, which is "Cell", right?

Comment: register the cell inside delegate method not once in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Is your cell class code written in objective-c? If yes try replicating same view (means re-creating not assigning classname) with swift language. Hope it works for you.

Comment: And filename in Navigator?

Comment: Registering the cells directly before the dequeue method did also not work

Comment: Check if `cellNib` isn't `nil` before registering.

Comment: cellNib isn't `nil`

Comment: Is it possible you're assigning another instance of `UICollectionView` to your `collection` variable somewhere?

Comment: In your xib File  did you have any identifier  ? and also check to register class also work or not ?

Comment: I tried to also register the class, it had the same outcome. The xib file does have the cell identifier as well

Comment: That's problem .1)  You need to register cell identifier in  XIB, 2) Assign Class name to XIB 3) cell for row you need to check with  as? YourClass in dequeue and 4)  dequeue with same identifier you   assign to XIB and register

Comment: It turns out the cell identifier and the cell identifier in the xib were different. Now it works, thank you @MikeAlter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is problem

1) You need to register cell identifier in XIB,

2) Assign Class name to XIB

3) cell for row you need to check with as? YourClass in dequeue and

4) dequeue with same identifier you assign to XIB and register

Answer (score 1):

Set collectionview cell identifier as Cell in storyboard.

[image]

Comment: assigning cell identifier not necessary while using custom nib for cell.

Comment: The collection view in my storyboard does not have a collection reusable view.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know why this crash is happening?

One thing to consider is that [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618083-register) for `register(_:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:)` say:

> *The nib file must contain only one top-level object and that object must be of the type UICollectionViewCell.*

So, check that that's true. In other words...

```
let nibObjects = cellNib.instantiate(withOwner: nib, options: nil)
let count = nibObjects.count  // is this 1?
let view = nibObjects.first   // is view a UICollectionViewCell?
```